# Как получить ссылку на диалог с пользователем в ВК Боте на Python?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Я хочу создать команду "Вызов администратора" для своего чат-бота, и чтобы к сообщению администратору прикреплялась ссылка на диалог, чтобы его можно было открыть сразу.

Я знаю, что такое возможно, я попытался найти методы в документации, но безуспешно.

Comment: Какое в итоге решение вы нашли?

Comment: То же самое, что и в ответе на мой вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ссылка на диалог с пользователем в группе строится следующим образом

```
vk.com/gim[group_id]?sel=[user_id]
```

Допустим, ID нашей группы - 33333, а ID пользователя - 11111, тогда ссылка будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
vk.com/gim33333?sel=11111
```

Из этого следует, что вам нужно всего лишь подставлять необходимые значения в строку формата `vk.com/gim[group_id]?sel=[user_id]`

Comment: Я уже успел обратиться в поддержку, но всё равно Вам спасибо!